# where's my spark sql query or dataframe executing?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code, it will read table from mysql database:

```
val jdbcDF = sparkSession.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "idbc:mysql location")
  .option("dbtable", "tablename")
  .option("user", "root")
  .option("password", "root")
  .load().where(some condition)
```

My questions:

1. While loading ,I am filtering the records based on certain condition. So where condition query will be executed on mysql server and return the result?
2. If I am just loading the table from any database. How the my table records will be distrbuted across cluster, who is reponsible doing it?

Comment: all the data is loaded in memory from mysql and then where condition is applied

Comment: Thanks for the reply . how the data will distributed across nodes..who is doing that ..based on ??

Comment: Ideally, you setup a partitioning key for Spark to distribute the database table scan

Comment: If you want the where statement to be done by the database engine (mysql), see https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#push-down-a-query-to-the-database-engine

Comment: As cricket_007 says, you have to define the partitioning by yourself in spark unless you use distributed system where data is partitioned by default as HDFS. And when shuffling happens in processing then the data is partitioned into 200 partitions.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan i 'm using distributed system .if i did't mentioned partitioning by myself . how my data will be partitioned by default as HDFS .Here i am not saving my tables in HDFS . I just processing the tables from mysql through spark .Was little confused here

Answer (score 0):

1. Unless you will perform some action spark won’t execute anything even filter condition and also copying data into memory. It’s lazy evaluation.
2. The code you have written once action will be performed data will be pulled into memory and then filter will be applied. If you want to execute filter in MySQL then pass the query instead of table name in the dbtable option.

Comment: seems a reasonable answer